# Horizontal lines on table not showing when exporting to HTML

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

I have this table,

```
|   A |   B |   C |
|-----+-----+-----|
| 123 | 123 | 123 |
|-----+-----+-----|
|   4 |   5 |   5 |
|-----+-----+-----|
|   3 |   2 |   1 |
|-----+-----+-----|
|     |     |     |
```

and I would like the horizontal lines between rows to show when published: they show up on PDF export, but not on HTML export. Do you know why?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you're doing. Don't expect readers to just follow a link to a bunch of code. State your question clearly and succinctly, saying what you tried etc. Thx.

Comment: I want to have horizontal lines between rows. I put the horizontal lines as shown on the sample (first three rows above) but when I publish I don't see the horizontal lines. What other information do I need to supply?

Comment: Published to `pdf` or `html`?

Comment: Since there are dozens of ways to export an org file to some other format, it is often best to dive into the documentation and even the source code for the specific export method you are using and figure out how it can be changed to do what you want. For example, if you are exporting to HTML then there is probably an option to specify a custom style sheet. You could use that and then write a stylesheet which adds in the cell borders that you prefer.

Comment: @FranBurstall I publish to html.

Comment: @FranBurstall Yes, when published to pdf lines show.

Comment: What's the value of `org-html-table-default-attributes`?

Comment: FWIW, both FF and Chrome show horizontal lines here. The setting of the variable above is the default setting: `(:border "2" :cellspacing "0" :cellpadding "6" :rules "groups" :frame "hsides")`.

Comment: @NickD I have the same default settings for that variable. Since you see the lines, it seems like this is related to my browser settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to add CSS within your org file, which will also avoid having to insert a `hline` between each row in the table. Table attributes can be customized further, but to get horizontal borders **for all rows** the following could be used:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">
#+HTML_HEAD: tr {border-bottom: 1px solid;}
#+HTML_HEAD: </style>
|   A |   B |   C |
|-----+-----+-----|
| 123 | 123 | 123 |
|   4 |   5 |   5 |
|   3 |   2 |   1 |
|     |     |     |
```

As mentioned it [the org manual](https://orgmode.org/org.html#CSS-support), this will override any settings from `org-html-table-default-attributes`.

---

To add borders **for only certain rows**, the CSS can be modified to use [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child). For example, to add a border to only the first 3 rows:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">
#+HTML_HEAD: tr:nth-child(-n+3) {border-bottom: 3px solid;}
#+HTML_HEAD: </style>
```

Comment: That will work (well, I *think* it will work, but I haven't tried it out) if you want borders after every row, but not if you want them after *some* rows only (again, I haven't tried it out, so that's what I *think* is the case).

Comment: Yea that's correct, you would have to modify the CSS to use the `nth-child` and customize it from there. For example `tr:nth-child(-n+3) {border-bottom: 3px solid;}` to add a bottom border for only the first 3 rows.

Comment: @c_48 Thanks! That works great.